# CSS - How to align <span> content to middle using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experiencing some issues while i'm trying to put `<span>` content aligned to middle:

[image]

I'm using bootstrap and i want to align middle the price `value` or `No price found. Ask price`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3erhxr1j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3erhxr1j/2/
By adding equal height and line height to the wrapping div, you can then center what's inside with vertical align.

```
.text-center.col-xs-12.col-sm-3{
   height: 120px;
   line-height: 120px;
}

h3{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
}
```